# Asembler MIPS program - work but not correctly

Tags: assembly, ascii, mips

I have a program like this:

Write a MIPS assembly language program that reads a string from the keyboard and then displays to the console how many characters, numbers, lowercase and uppercase letters, and spaces were in it.

but the program, after running it, which I have already done, returns me wrong values as to the number of lowercase and uppercase characters and numbers, exactly like this:

```
Enter BaDstring: Example text 41 45
The introduced BaDcuch contains:
24
24 digits
24 lowercase letters
24 capital letters
24 spaces
-- program is finished running --
```

After entering the string: "Sample text 41 45"

My program:

```
.date
     prompt: .asciiz "Enter the string: "
     result: .asciiz "Entered string contains:\n"
     newline: .asciiz "\n"
     digits: .asciiz "digits"
     lowercase: .asciiz "lower case"
     uppercase: .asciiz "upper case"
     spaces: .asciiz " spaces"

.text
.globl main
main:
     # Printing the prompt
     li$v0, 4
     la $a0, prompt
     syscall

     # Read a string of characters
     li $v0.8
     la $a0, buffer
     li $a1, 256
     syscall

     # Initialization of variables
     li $t0, 0 # Total character count
     li $t1, 0 # Number of digits
     li $t2, 0 # Lower case counter
     li $t3, 0 # Upper case counter
     li $t4, 0 # Space counter

     # String processing
     la $t5, buffer # Address of the first character
     lb $t6, ($t5) # Read the first character

loop:
     beqz $t6, done # Exit if null character encountered (end of string)

     addi $t0, $t0, 1 # Increment the counter of all characters

# Check if a character is a number
li $t7, 48 # '0' in ASCII
li $t8, 58 # ':' in ASCII code - limit value
slt $t9, $t6, $t8 # Is the character less than ':', 58 in ASCII?
slt $t8, $t7, $t6 # Is '0' less than a sign?
and $t8, $t8, $t9 # Are both conditions met?
addi $t1, $t1, 1 # Increment the digit counter if the condition is met

  # Check if a character is a lowercase letter
li $t7, 97 # 'a' in ASCII
li $t8, 123 # 123 in ASCII code - limit value
slt $t9, $t6, $t8 # Is the character less than '{'?
slt $t8, $t7, $t6 # Is 'a' less than a sign?
and $t8, $t8, $t9 # Are both conditions met?
addi $t2, $t2, 1 # Increment the lower case counter if the condition is true

# Check if a character is an uppercase letter
li $t7, 65 # 'A' in ASCII
li $t8, 91 # 91 in ASCII code - limit value
slt $t9, $t6, $t8 # Is the character less than '['?
slt $t8, $t7, $t6 # Is 'A' less than a sign?
and $t8, $t8, $t9 # Are both conditions met?
addi $t3, $t3, 1 # Increment the upper case counter if the condition is met

# Check if a character is a space
li $t7, 32 # ASCII space
beq $t6, $t7, increment_space # Increment space counter if character is a space

increment_space:
     addi $t4, $t4, 1 # Increment the space counter

     addi $t5, $t5, 1 # Go to next character
     lb $t6, ($t5) # Load next character
     j-loop

done:
     # Displaying results
     li$v0, 4
     la $a0, result
     syscall

     # Display the number of all characters
     li$v0, 1
     move $a0, $t0
     syscall

     li$v0, 4
     la $a0, newline
     syscall

     # Display number of digits
     li$v0, 1
     move $a0, $t1
     syscall

     li$v0, 4
     la $a0, digits
     syscall

     li$v0, 4
     la $a0, newline
     syscall

     # Display the number of lowercase letters
     li$v0, 1
     move $a0, $t2
     syscall

     li$v0, 4
     la $a0, lowercase
     syscall

     li$v0, 4
     la $a0, newline
     syscall

     # Display the number of capital letters
     li$v0, 1
     move $a0, $t3
     syscall

     li$v0, 4
     la $a0, uppercase
     syscall

     li$v0, 4
     la $a0, newline
     syscall

     # Display the number of spaces
     li$v0, 1
     move $a0, $t4
     syscall

     li$v0, 4
     la $a0, spaces
     syscall

     li $v0, 10 # End of program
     syscall

.date
     buffer: .space 256 # Buffer for the read string
```

Comment: So, try debugging it.  Use a very small input and single step in the debugger.  If it's counting something wrong, then it will be doing it in a very specific and observable way,  You should have a good idea of how this needs to work in a language with structured statements (like C or Java), so compare a working version in high level language to what your assembly code is doing.

Comment: FYI, you're always adding 1 unconditionally for most categories.  And your increment space operation is a not properly constructed if-then, so also always incrementing.

Comment: Thank you, i did some updates and its working

Comment: Your approach of creating a 0 or 1 value and then summing that boolean is good.  This is branchless programming, which is very good for modern processor performance (unpredictable branches hurt performance, the branches are taken/not taken base on input data, nothing that the processor could predict ahead of time).

Comment: You can do similar for the equal to space counter.  One approach is to subtract the space value (32) using `subiu`, then use `sltiu` to compare with constant 1, obtaining a 0/1 value.  If the character value was 32 (space) then it will be < 1 in unsigned, i.e. 0 meaning was exactly 32, so that yields a 0/1 for equality.  If the value wasn't 32 (space) then it won't be zero, and it will be 1 or higher (if > 32), or else appear very large when negative number (i.e. < 32) is viewed by unsigned compare, in either case < 1 only when exactly 0.